# How to disable slider tick in YUI?

Tags: javascript, slider, yui

I am using YUI slider control in my application. I want to disable the slider ticks so that the user can not move it based on my application's condition. How to do that? Please someone help me.

Comment: Do you want to remove the tick indicators, or disable the movement of the slider? Or make the slider move freeform?

Comment: Which version of YUI are you using: the slider API in YUI2 is very different than the same in YUI3.

Comment: I just want to disable the movement of the slider. I tried lock method of the slider but it is not working. I am using YUI2

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called lock()

see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Slider.html#method_lock
for this

you said you tried it but how exactly did you call that method?

Comment: I tried like this YAHOO.widget.Slider.cutslid.lock(); edit: cutslid is the slider object i am using.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, i know it's kinda late now, but it's better than never.  i tried to solve this issue for hours.  i hope my solution helps.

The slider's lock() can disable dragdrop/keying/click interaction of the slider but it will somehow lock() at 'slideStart' event. Thus, even though you call slider.setValue() to populate the slider's value, it will always lock() at the leftmost position, e.g. 0.

IMO, the best way to do it is as follows:

```
slider.setValue(100, false);

if(!writePermission) {
  slider.subscribe('slideEnd', function(){slider.lock();}); //locks slider when it ends the drag animation
}
```

timmow's solution works only if user clicks on the slider's background but user can still drag the slider's thumb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the events the slider fires - these are documented [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/slider/#events), and also [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/DD.html#events) as the slider inherits from the drag and drop widget

For example, the following should work

```
YAHOO.widget.Slider.cutslid.subscribe('b4MouseDownEvent', function() {YAHOO.widget.Slider.cutslid.lock()});
```